# Re-route network traffic on Android 5

Tags: android, android-networking

I have an application where I need to be connected to a WiFi which has no Internet connection. However, there is specific traffic which I need to route over LTE. With the new Android multi-networking API it should be possible to achieve this but I cannot find any tutorials.

Does anybody have an example how to stay connected to a WiFi without access to the Internet but reroute specific requests over LTE?

Comment: I have found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7041370/how-to-reroute-all-ip-traffic-pref-at-the-network-layer-in-android-3-x but that's for android 3.0 so I don't know about 5.0

Comment: Hi, thank you very much, but I am looking for a solution with the new multi networking API, which was introduced with Android 5.